# Using vectors to show a fact about a regular n-gon

Tags: geometry, vectors

Suppose we have a regular n-gon $X_1X_2...X_n$ with center $O$. Im trying to prove that

$$ \vec{OX_1}+... + \vec{OX_n} = \vec{0}$$

Im trying to show this using induction. If we start with triangle, say $\triangle X_1X_2X_3 $, we want to show $\vec{OX_1} + \vec{OX_2} + \vec{OX_3} = \vec{0}$. Is it enough to show this case? Perhaps is it easier if we do directly the $n-case$?

Answer (score 5):

Consider a rotation $R$ which is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$-rotation. Assume that $v:=\sum_i OX_i $ Then $$ Rv=\sum_i R(OX_i)=\sum_i OX_i=v $$

Hence $v$ is invariant under rotation That is $v=0$

[Add]

If $X_n:=X_0$ note that $\{X_i-X_{i-1} \}_{i=1}^n$ forms a regular
$n$-gon Clearly $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X_{i-1})=0$

Comment: Can you prove using elementary math ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the $n$-gon is regular, $X_1,...,X_n$ are in the circle of radius $r=\|\vec{OX_j}\|,\ j\in\{1,...,n\}$ and without loss of generality (we can take a rotation and use the fact that for fixed $n$ $n$-gons are congruent) $X_j$'s are $n$-th roots of equation $X^n-r=0$. By Vieta's formula its sum is equal to $0$.